# Display first occurrence after a class that is nested

Tags: css

I want the first class **.tab** immediately following the class **.tab-wrapper** to be visible, the rest should not be displayed

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-wrapper">
    <div class="tab">VISIBLE</div>
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="tab">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-wrapper">
            <div class="tab">VISIBLE</div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
            <div class="tab"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my css. For some reason the first .tab of the second .tab-wrapper does not display...
How do i fix it?
Thanks

```
.tab-wrapper .tab {display: none;}
.tab-wrapper .tab:first-child {display: block;}
```

Comment: If you hide a container, everything inside it is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

This is working, although when I copied/pasted your code it did not? (Of course, copying your CSS into the fiddle now appears to work. If you're trying to get the second `VISIBLE` to display, you're out of luck unless you modify your methodology.)

```
.tab-wrapper .tab {
    display: none;
}
.tab-wrapper .tab:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zW7dz/

Also, as @barmar points out, your second inner/inner `.tab` can't be shown because it's parent (`.tab`) is going to get the `display: none`. You can't see it if it's parent is not visible.